# Rails - Gem CanCanCan e Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Uso as gems 'devise' e 'cancancan' e também a 'rails_admin' em meu projeto.

Todas elas para a parte administrativa do site.Está funcionando perfeitamente essa parte.Porem em minha pagina principal do site(root) não deveria precisar de autenticação para acessa-la,mas está sendo requisitando o login para entrar na mesma.

Adicionei `before_action :authenticate_user!` no application_controller como recomendado pelo devise,imagino que pode ser por isso.

Enfim,gostaria de saber como restrinjo e exijo login apenas em algumas paginas do site. E não nas que os usuarios deveriam acessar sem a necessidade de um login,como por exemplo no ROOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toda vez que a função `authenticate_user!` é chamada, então o Devise obriga que precise de um usuário.

O que eu faria nesse caso, é criar um `ApplicationController` somente para a sua parte que precisa de autenticação, da seguinte forma:

```
# app/controllers/admin_controller.rb
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

Modificaria todos os controllers que precisem de autenticação para herdarem `AdminController` ao invés de `ApplicationController` e removeria o `before_action :authenticate_user!` de `ApplicationController`.

Dessa forma, somente os controllers que herdarem de `AdminController` requisitariam autenticação do Devise.

Comment: Obrigado,ja tinha resolvido.Porém sua explicação foi muito boa,melhor do que a que eu havia recebido!